# 404 Not found for sitemap.xml on nuxt.js

Tags: javascript, nginx, nuxt.js, sitemap

I am using nuxt.js [sitemap-module](https://github.com/nuxt-community/sitemap-module/) to generate sitemap.xml
It working perfectly with `npm run build && npm run start` on local.

However, it won't work when it's on the cloud with Nginx. https://vtapau.com/sitemap.xml

Here is my Nginx config

```
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name vtapau.com www.vtapau.com;

        location / {
                proxy_pass http://localhost:8081/;
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_redirect off;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I really has no idea if this is valid answer to you as you mentioned you've put manually created sitemap into static folder.

I think you misconfigured the sitemap, for sitemap.xml to work, you set routes inside sitemap object:

```
// nuxt.config.js

{
  sitemap: {
    hostname: 'https://example.com',
    gzip: true,
    exclude: [
      '/secret',
      '/admin/**'
    ],
    routes: [
      '/page/1',
      '/page/2',
      {
        url: '/page/3',
        changefreq: 'daily',
        priority: 1,
        lastmod: '2017-06-30T13:30:00.000Z'
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

When I was asked to select language, I suspected that your sitemap has split into different languages. I managed to get English version sitemap [here](https://vtapau.com/sitemap-en.xml).

If your sitemap configuration is like below:

```
// nuxt.config.js

{
   sitemap: {
     hostname: 'https://example.com',
     lastmod: '2017-06-30',
     sitemaps: [
       {
          path: '/sitemap-foo.xml',
          routes: ['foo/1', 'foo/2'],
          gzip: true
       }, {
          path: '/folder/sitemap-bar.xml',
          routes: ['bar/1', 'bar/2'],
          exclude: ['/**']
       }
     ]
   }
}
```

You should able to get your sitemap at https://vtapau.com/sitemapindex.xml. I hope this is not the static xml you've created otherwise nothing I could help already. This documentation was clearly mentioned at [sitemap-module](https://github.com/nuxt-community/sitemap-module/), when things configured wrongly always go back to the github documentation or find answer through github issues there.

- Also great to see Malaysia new startup in food delivering.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the exact same issue. Then I found out that the in the production server the Nuxt server were started using `nuxt start` instead of what I was using `nuxt-ts start` locally. Which it was the issue in my case. Hope this help you.

Comment: Hi there, I use pm2 to start, and it is `nuxt-ts start` as well. Thanks for your help anyway!

Answer (score 0):

Restart your PM2 server after you run `npm run build`. Otherwise, the /sitemap.xml will not appear.

This has been the case for me.

My config for sitemap module:

```
sitemap: {
   hostname: 'https://example.com',
   gzip: true,
   exclude: ['/exampleurl']
}
```

Comment: I have done that. Not sure whether it's because I am using bitbucket pipeline with AWS CodeDeploy

Answer (score 0):

I fix the same bug on AWS lambda deployment using Typescript config file `nuxt.config.ts`.

To fix it replace `const config: NuxtConfig = { }`
to `module.exports = { }`